# MS Flow runs one hour later

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, timezone

Hi I have a flow that runs once an item get updated in a SP list. The list has a date/time column and one yes/no. So when the user create a item, he/she set a time when the yes/no column will get updated. 
The flow runs when the item is created, get the date from the date column and pauses until the right time is reached, this part is inside a Delay until aciton. 
The problem is that the flow continues allways on hour after the time that the user selected. If the user selected 22:00, the flow pauses and continues at 23:00 instead of 22:00 as the user selected.

I tested with different time zones but there is not difference. 
I am usign this form to get the date/time from the column:

```
convertFromUtc(triggerBody()?['Start'],'W. Europe Standard Time','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ')
```

I am in sweden, which is UTC+1 but I have also tried this one:

```
convertFromUtc(triggerBody()?['Start'],'Cape Verde Standard Time','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ')
```

which is UTC-1 but the flow still restarting on hour later than the user selected.

What ir wrong?

Heres is an update:

The time zone issue is solved. The issue now is that in a library I have the same type of time column but I can't get the value in MS Flow. 
I created a variable and later (inside a conditional) I initialize it with the date value from the date column. It look like this:

[image: Initializing variable]

The code I am using is this one:

```
not(empty(item()?['Schedule_x0020_publishing_x0020_date']))
```

Where 'Schedule_x0020_publishing_x0020_date' is the date/time column. I tried with 'triggerBody' instead of 'item' but there is no difference. This is what Flow says:

[image: The field is empty]

An I now that there is a date in the column!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the time zone of the SharePoint site to UTC

Site settings -> Regional settings -> Change Time zone

[image]

A similar issue for your refernence:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/SharePoint-Flow-Date-Time-conversion-not-working-correclty/m-p/146671#M15104

Comment: Thanks that worked! Now I have another issue. Can you check the update in my post?

Comment: If proposed solution has resolved your issue you should mark it as answer and open a new question with new thread.

Comment: For another issue, I recommend you create a new thread for it. one question one post.